Should I use WITH or not?

She makes exactly two cups of rice everyday. What if she only wants to make exactly two cups of quinoa? Like she does/does with white rice?

Should I leave or use "with" in the sentence above?

Can you be a bit clearer on what you want to write, separating quotations from other text, and clearly saying what the alternatives are. "Like she does with white rice?" is fine in a casual context, although not in formal writing. And other parts are a bit awkward: "What if she wants to make exactly two cups of quinoa instead?" might be better, though still fairly informal.

Are you confused as to whether you should say  (1) Like she does with white rice OR (2) Like does with white rice OR (3) Like she does white rice. The question is confusing because it's not clear what your problem is.

I think I understand the question.  When she makes white rice, she makes two cups. That is her regular practice. But today she wants to make quinoa, but just two cups of quinoa, like she does white rice.    Is that sentence grammatical, or is with needed before "white rice" in the bolded phrase?

If "with" is not provided, then  something like "when making" or "when she makes" or "with" would be understood.  It would be understood as a form of ellipsis. like she does white rice relies on the earlier sentences for its meaning. The earlier sentences fill the gap: like she does [gap] white rice.

I should add that this sort of ellipsis is very common in conversational contexts, but in expository writing far less so.

This particular ellipsis would usually be used for a manner of making something, but using it for the amount seems confusing to me. Using "with" is clearer.

She makes exactly two cups of rice everyday. What if she only wants to make exactly two cups of quinoa? Like she does/does with white rice?
Question: Is with OK? Answer: Yes, it is.
Is it required? No, it can be left out in this case.
If you do x with y, you can use it. She makes two cups like she did with brown rice yesterday.
That said, conversationally, we often add with.

He played the same pieces brilliantly yesterday. Just like he did (with) Mozart yesterday.
He won the game with great gusto. Just like he did (with) the one in Cleveland.


@MariosAthanasiou Most of what people say about this supposed difference in BrE and AnE is not right. It's just that there is so much more "media" from the states that people get that impression. I have already told you that this thing where you upvote me cannot be a reason for my upvoting you. I would upvote you if you answer was right.
